# How to create an opt-out cookie

Tags: html, cookies

I need to create a third party opt-out cookie and I am confused on how to do it?  I will have an opt-out button on my webpage and when someone clicks it then it should opt out so if I see that cookie on another website then I will not do anything with that cookie id.

1) Do I need to get the user cookie and store int in my database?
2) Do I need to place a cookie that will tell me if that user opted out?

Basically..I am confused about the workflow on best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> so if I see that cookie on another website

You will never see that cookie on another website which is on a different domain because cookies cannot be shared between domains. So I guess that your best bet is to store this information into a database. Then the other site might either directly access this database (depending on your architecture) or you could expose it as web service that this other site will consume to know whether a given user has opted out.

Now if on the other hand the sites are on the same root domain (like `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`) you could share a cookie between them. You just need to set the [Domain property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) of the cookie when generating it to the root domain (`.example.com`).